# Trouble in MySQL querying

Tags: mysql

I am currently developing a digital mobile loyalty app and I have face a problem in querying mysql code...

I have 4 tables: `Customer, Card, Redemption, Merchant`

Currently what I am trying to do is that I want my system to first check if the customer possess the loyalty card of a certain merchant when they are making a redemption

- If yes, then they can just proceed
- If no, the system will create a card for them and proceed

The redemption code will be generated by the merchant...

The problem is how should I query my code to do so?

```
Customer

 - Customer_ID
 - C_Email
 - C_Password
 - C_Name

Card

 - Card_ID
 - Chop_Amt
 - Customer_ID*
 - Merchant_ID*

Merchant

 - Merchant_ID
 - Merchant_Name

Redemption

 - Red_ID
 - Red_Code
 - Card_ID*
 - Merchant_ID*
```

I tried writing a code my own just now...can some1 please help me check?

```
select * 
from customer customer 
join card card 
  on customer.customer_id = card.customer_id 
join redemption redemption 
  on card.merchant_id = redemption.merchant_id 
where card.merchant_id = redemption.merchant_id and
      redemption.red_code = 'A002'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting a unique index on the Card table for merchant / customer entries. IF you go with this approach, you can do an INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id. This will ensure that a record exists regardless.

**To create the index, do this**

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer_merchant ON Card (Customer_ID, Merchant_ID);
```

Now that you have that in place, go ahead and do the insert, which will NOT insert a new row if one already exists

```
INSERT INTO Card (Chop_Amt, Customer_ID, Merchant_ID) VALUES(0.00, 1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Card_ID = Card_ID
```

The UPDATE Card_ID = Card_ID part is simply an alias to "don't do anything", as it's setting the Card_ID to itself

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Will implement it :D